# Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular

The error comes when i sellect the encounter.dateOfService data i dont know why it comes i tried getting the response by using response.data.But the error still exist any idea where i'm missing out or what might be the code error. Any help will be appreciated.I received a json data from api. And this how my api data looks

```
    {
  "expires_in": 0,
  "data": {
    "patientEncounterTemplate": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "patientEncounterId": 2,
        "masterTemplateId": 1,
        "templateData": "",
        "templateJson": "",
        "isDeleted": false
      }
    ],
    "id": 2,
    "patientID": 6,
    "patientAppointmentId": 60,
    "dateOfService": "2021-03-02T12:00:00",
    "startDateTime": "2021-03-02T12:00:00",
    "endDateTime": "2021-03-02T13:00:00",
    "appointmentStartDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "appointmentEndDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "staffID": 10,
    "officeAddressID": 1,
    "serviceLocationID": 1,
    "notetypeId": 1,
    "staffName": "Staff 1",
    "patientName": "Rahul Singh",
    "locationName": "Eveda",
    "status": "Pending",
    "totalRecords": 0,
    "unitsBlocked": 0,
    "unitsConsumed": 0,
    "serviceFacility": "62 - Comprehensive Outpatient ",
    "isDirectService": true,
    "isBillableEncounter": false,
    "soapNotes": {
      "id": 2,
      "subjective": "",
      "objective": "",
      "assessment": "",
      "plans": ""
    },
    "patientEncounterServiceCodes": [],
    "patientEncounterDiagnosisCodes": [],
    "encounterSignature": []
  },
  "message": "Success",
  "statusCode": 200,
  "appError": "",
  "firstTimeLogin": false,
  "openDefaultClient": false
}
```

and this is how i called the data

```
getSelectedPreviousEncountersData(event:any){
    debugger
   this.previousEncounterId = event;
   this.encounterService.getPreviousEncountersData(this.previousEncounterId)
   .subscribe(
     response => {
       if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        debugger
         this.previousEncounters=response.data;
         if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          debugger
          console.log(this.previousEncounters)
          this.isPreviousEncounter=true;
          this.encounterId=0;
          this.soapNotes = response.data.soapNotes || null;
          this.patientEncounterTemplate = response.data.patientEncounterTemplate || [];
          this.templateFormId = response.data.patientEncounterTemplate && 
          response.data.patientEncounterTemplate[0].masterTemplateId || 0;

        } else {
          this.soapNotes = null;
          this.unitsConsumed = 0;
          this.isSoapCompleted = false;
        }
        debugger
        if (this.previousEncounterId) {
          this.getTemplateForm(this.templateFormId);
        }
       }
     }
   )
  }
```

and this is the html i i have

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                  <mat-select placeholder="Select Previous Encounters"
                                      [(value)]="previousEncounterId"
                                      (selectionChange)="getSelectedPreviousEncountersData($event.value)">
                                      <mat-option *ngFor="let encounter of previousEncounters"
                                          [value]="encounter.id">
                                          {{ encounter.dateOfService }}
                                      </mat-option>
                                  </mat-select>
                              </mat-form-field>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                          <div class="filter-btn d-flex justify-content-end">
                              <button type="button" class="rounded px-1" color="warn"
                                  mat-raised-button (click)="clearFilters()">Clear All</button>
                              <button name="Filter" mat-raised-button class="rounded px-1 ml-3"
                                  color="accent" (click)="applyFilter()">Filter</button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

Now i found out that i'm trying to access object not an array encounter.dateOfService is not an array so how can i convert json object into array.

```
applyFilter() {
    debugger
    let formValues = this.soapForm.value;
    this.getPreviousEncounters(this.patientAppointmentDetails.patientID, formValues.fromDate ? format(formValues.fromDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') : "", formValues.toDate ? format(formValues.toDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') : "");
  }

getPreviousEncounters(patientId, fromDate, toDate){

    this.encounterService.getPreviousEncounters(patientId, fromDate, toDate)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          this.previousEncounters=response.data;
          this.previousEncounterId=response.data.id;
          this.previousEncounters = (response.data || []).map((obj: any) => {
            obj.dateOfService = format(obj.dateOfService, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
            return obj;
          });

          //Legasov Added
          ////this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
        }
        else{
          this.previousEncounters=[];
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Could you add your applyFilter() function in your question?

Comment: how can i convert json object into an array. I found out that encounter.dateOfService is not an array

Comment: It is too simple Mike. Create an array and add your json data to that array. Eg. const data = {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null};
const arr = [];
arr.push(data);

Comment: not working i tried. data comes blank

Comment: are you sure that you need iterate over `previousEncounters`? Its the whole response  object. The only property that seems iterable is `patientEncounterTemplate`. Probably you are not using the correct property for mat-options

Comment: @MikeMicky If so, add your applyFilter() function to your question. Let me check detail.

Comment: i have added the apllyfilter code